# Terraform Kubernetes provider not found

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I am trying to use the kubernetes provider in my project using the [recommended configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs) and get the following error:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
Finding hashicorp/kubernetes versions matching "1.13.2"...
Error: Failed to query available provider packages
Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
hashicorp/kubernetes: provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes was
not found in any of the search locations
```

I run terraform init (0.13) in my local environment and everything goes ok. But when I push it to our repo the previous error shows. We have a plugin folder in the repo for terraform plugins where others plugins are saved. Any idea what is broken?